# WCF Expose Inherited Class

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

Why is the Inherited Class not exposed when I use this WCF Service Class?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract] void DoSomething();
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class InheritMe
{
    [DataMember] public int ExposeMe { get; set; }
}

public class MyService : InheritMe, IMyService
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

My code is in C#, in Framework 4, build in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by not exposed?

Comment: In client application, the ExposeMe DataMember is not exposed.

Comment: Why would you want to make your service class a data contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExposeMe` is not part of the service contract. If you expect to be able to call it in client applicaitons, then you have to define it in the contract interface `IMyService`.

It's is a little wierd to have your service class (`MyService`) inherit from a `DataContract`. This serves no purpose. `DataContact` classes are classes that you can communicate to the client (by returning them from your service operations for example).
The `MyService` class is just the implementation of your service contract - it is not visible to the client.

Comment: There were methods in the InheritMe class that uses the ExposeMe property in my actual code. Thanks, I'll try what you suggest.

Comment: It works, but unfortunately, I remember that MySqlCommand.MySqlTransaction is not serializable. Haha. Thanks again.